# Insert text at caret from button in RichTextBox mvvm using wpf toolkit

Tags: mvvm, prism, richtextbox, wpftoolkit

I have selected text from a ListBox that I want to insert into a RichTextBox at the caret position.  I can get the selected text to be inserted at the end of the text string.

I am not sure how to pass the RichTextBox caret position to my view model.

Here is part of my code for the project.

```
            <Button x:Name="AddItemBtn" Content="Add Item" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="417,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Command="{Binding AddItemBtn}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AddItemList,Path=SelectedItem}"/>
        <wpftoolkit:RichTextBox  Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TestText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" x:Name="MyEditor" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" IsDocumentEnabled="True" AcceptsTab="True" AcceptsReturn="True" >
            <wpftoolkit:RichTextBox.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" ></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </wpftoolkit:RichTextBox.Resources>
            <wpftoolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
                <wpftoolkit:PlainTextFormatter/>
            </wpftoolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
        </wpftoolkit:RichTextBox>
```

Here is the view model part.

```
        private string _testText;
    public string TestText
    {
        get
        {
            return _testText;
        }

        set
        {
            //_testText = _testText + value;
            SetProperty(ref _testText, value);
        }

    }

    public ICommand AddItemBtn
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void addItem(Tabbed selectedItem)
    {
        if (selectedItem != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.Command);
            if (TestText != null)
            {
                TestText = TestText.ToString() + selectedItem.Command;
            }
            else
            {
                TestText =  selectedItem.Command;
            }

        }
    }
```

I tried a flowdocument but still could not get the parameters to pass correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I like to put a function on the view model that is setup in the view code behind.

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Func<int> GetCarrotPosition { get; set; }
    //...
```

Looks like you can get the number of characters into the text string by getting the offset from the document start start to the current position

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        // InitializeComponent stuff..
        var castedContext = (MainViewModel)DataContext;
        castedContext.GetCarrotPosition = () =>
        {
            // Placing the cursor at the start of the text returns a value of 2, so I subtract 2 to get the current cursor location
            return MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition.DocumentStart.GetOffsetToPosition(MyRichTextBox.CaretPosition) - 2; 
        };
        //...
```

Finally, call the GetCarrotPosition() function in your command

```
    var carrotPosition = GetCarrotPosition();
    TestText.Insert(carrotPosition, selectedItem.Command);
```

Creating delegates on the view model that get wired up in the view code behind is the sexiest MVVM way of working with UI elements I know of.

Comment: Besides that you could do all this in an attached behavior and have something actually (re-)usable instead of ending up with half of your view model in the code behind of one specfic view...